# Crystal Reports Date range Multiple fields

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to have a user only enter one date parameter to look up multiple fields. Currently they have to enter a new parameter for each field. Is there a way to enter a range and if any field matches that criteria it would show on the report? I have six fields i would like to query.I used this formula to test just 2 fields.  The problem I have is that if {field one} does not meet the parameter it will not show {field 2} if it meets the parameter.

({CUST_ContactsTable1_114806.CUST_Dog1BatteryPlanStartDate_103625984}>={?Start Date}
and{CUST_ContactsTable1_114806.CUST_Dog1BatteryPlanStartDate_103625984}<={?End Date})OR
({CUST_ContactsTable1_114806.CUST_Dog2Batteryplanstartdate_070133812}>={?Start Date}
and{CUST_ContactsTable1_114806.CUST_Dog2Batteryplanstartdate_070133812}<={?End Date})

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you've specified the query here, I would expect this to work.

Two ideas:
1. Is there something else in your record or group selection formulas that could be causing the query to return/not return rows?
2. Are you sure that Crystal is treating both the database field and the two parameters as dates or datetimes?  Sometimes Crystal can get confused if you're not using the best DB drivers for your database, and it will revert to doing string comparisons vs date comparisons which can cause seemingly odd behavior if the dates are not interpreted in a yyyyMMdd "biggest to smallest"-style format.

If those don't seem to work, please paste the whole SQL query (you can get this from the Report menu under "show SQL query...") and an example of some rows you would expect to come back and some rows you would expect to be filtered based on certain parameters.